# How to set the `fields` parameter in the Google Drive GoogleAPIs v3 in Dart?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, dart, field

I'm trying to return back a specific set of fields for the File resource from the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource), v3, for Dart. As [specified](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration), the regular list() call returns back just 4 params, but if I pass in the query param for fields (e.g. `fields='starred,webContentLink'`), I can return back other information about the File. Likewise, passing in `fields='*'` returns back the entire File resource. This works fine in the 'Try this API' section of the documentation.

Right now, with the Dart package, setting `$fields: '*'` works, but setting `$fields: 'starred'` results in this error: `DetailedApiRequestError(status: 400, message: Invalid field selection starred)`.

```
// Assume I have successfully created an API client
g_drive.DriveApi api = new g_drive.DriveApi(client);
// This works
g_drive.FileList fileList = await api.files.list($fields: '*');
// This returns the 400 error
g_drive.FileList fileList = await api.files.list($fields: 'starred');
```

I went into the [actual v3 code](https://github.com/dart-lang/googleapis/blob/master/generated/googleapis/lib/drive/v3.dart#L1315) and manually changed `_queryParams["fields"]` to `starred`, but that didn't work either (`*` works). I even tried `'starred'` with the extra quotes just in case, but that resulted in the same error (`DetailedApiRequestError(status: 400, message: Invalid field selection 'starred')`)

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about the following modification?

#### From :

```
$fields: 'starred'
```

#### To :

```
$fields: 'files/starred'
```

or

```
$fields: 'files%2Fstarred'
```

If you want to retrieve a list with starred and filename, you can use `$fields: 'files(name,starred)'` or `$fields: 'files(name%2Cstarred)'`.

#### Reference :

- https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: `$fields: 'files/starred'` works. Thank you. This is confusing because the "Try this API" section of https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list doesn't require me to prepend my `fields` param with `files/`.

Comment: @Mary Welcome. Thank you, too. Yes. Also it had made me confuse. I thought that it was a bit difficult to find the parameters.

Comment: @Tanaike, can i get body data of image by drive list api. I want to store image in my system. if yes what is that field to pass in para.
I don't want to use another api https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId.

Comment: @Sourabh Bhutani "body data of image" cannot be retrieved with "drive list api".

Comment: this answer deserves some love. the documentation is catastrophic

Comment: @sousben Thank you for your comment.